# DXperience gridview and controls within

Tags: gridview, dxperience

I have am trying the trial of DXperience gridview, and was wondering if it is possible to attach a aspx control to one of the columns.

I have created a simple control which contains a button and some javascript/ajax methods, and would like to add it to a column, but is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dxprerience gridview supports templated columns just like the standard ASP.NET gridview. Using templates is what allows to embed your custom controls.

Please refer to the **[ASPxGridview Documentation](http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=ASPxGridView/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewTemplates_DataRowtopic.htm&levelup=true)** for examples.